# Save binary data get from url into Django FileField

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.7

Is there any ways to save a binary data get from an external url (in my case, an excel file) into a Django FileField, with the file uploaded to the destination according to the django project settings?

```
class FileData(models.Model):
    excel_file = models.FileField(upload_to='excel_file_path')


import requests
url = 'https://www.example.getfile.com/file_id=234'
r = requests.get(url)
# How to store the binary data response to FileField?
```

Thanks for help. Please also let me know if further information is needed in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of [`django.core.files.uploadedfile.SimpleUploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form) to save your content as a file field of your model instance.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

>>> response = requests.get("https://www.example.getfile.com/file_id=234")

>>> excel_file = SimpleUploadedFile("excel.xls", response.content, content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
>>> file_data = FileData(excel_file=excel_file)
>>> file_data.save()
```